# Fabric on iOS - new project, same bundleId - Answers/Crashlytics not working

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fabric.io

I have an app in the app store which has now been completely re-written from a new xcode project. The new project has the same bundle Id, and same Fabric APIKey [in the info.plist], and uses the same run-script command. 
However, events are not being passed up to Fabric, no purchases are registered in Answers and this new version is not appearing on my Fabric dashboard. 
I can't release unless I know Answers is working right (since it tells me my daily revenue etc).
Setting Fabric debug to true gives me this:

```
--- [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.1 (129)
--- [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone10,1, 12.0.0 (16A366)
--- [Answers] Initialized
--- [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.7";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.10.1";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.7.6";
}
--- [Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
    "flush_interval_secs" = 300;
    "flush_on_background" = 1;
    "forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
    "include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
    "sampling_rate" = 1;
    "track_custom_events" = 1;
    "track_predefined_events" = 1;
    "track_view_controllers" = 0;
    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
```

When an answers event is logged, I see this encouraging information:

```
--- [Answers] Logging Answers event: <ANSPredefinedEvent: purchase
{
    currency = USD;
    ...
    success = true;
}
{
}>
---  [Answers] Transmitting packaged events for '60C20825-0EA9-463B-974B-456D6E546366'.
---  [Answers] Finished transmission of '60C20825-0EA9-463B-974B-456D6E546366'.
```

How can I debug where the Answers data is going?

My code is straightforward [in AppDelegate]:

```
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug:YES];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Answers class]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is going up, but it is hidden in the web dashboard since I'm just one device vs the thousands of others.
The new versions can be seen on Settings > Apps > [your app] > Versions. The dashboard only really shows top versions so my new one didn't appear.
The purchase events can be better viewed on the Dashboard > Purchase > Item ID/Name [since I added some different IDs].